# How to chat from my S3 to my PC?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

I want to chat in realtime with my family who uses my Windows 7 desktop with their own profile account. Problem is they don't want to sign-up for anything on their end.  Now is there a such an app I can install on the desktop and my S3 that will pop-up messages on all the accounts on the desktop and not just my own Windows 7 account since I'll be the one signing up for whatever the chat app is...Viber needs a number so I will just end up messaging myself...I want to just be able to message using an installed app on the PC and not something that requires a browser window to be open.  Anyone know of anything like that?

os: 4.1

Comment: Do you want to just send a message to the PC, or do you also want them to reply from the PC?

Comment: @geffchang I want them to reply! :-)

Comment: There's a Chrome hangouts extension, but you'd have to sign in, any chat app will require a sign in. Most have died though (MSN is now gone) so I can't think of any way without using Hangouts or similar.

Comment: @RossC I know the desktop has to be signed in but unless my family uses the browser while I message them then it's pointless. I was hoping there was something that I can leave signed in and send messages to that will popup in all accounts not just my personal one.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't think there is such an app. 
You either send message to yourself (Viber, Skype etc.) and your parents answers to you (but basically to themself at the same time) or they sign up to something (perhaps you could sign them up, without having them do it). 
I have an idea, but that's kinda "original" (aka stupid): use something like TeamViewer to take control of the pc with your S3 and just use a blocknote to write. 
Easy, fast and no one has to signup to nothing xD